# Parameterized queries with VB/Classic ASP GetRows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, parameters

I am maintaining a system that runs Classic ASP, I was just wondering is there any easy way to adapt this function so I can use parameterized queries?

```
Function GetRSArray(strSQL)

    Set objRS = oConn.Execute(strSQL)

    If Not objRS.EOF Then 
        oFarrRS = objRS.GetRows()
        GetRSArray = oFarrRS
    Else
        GetRSArray = ""
    End if

    Set objRS = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: See this answer for more  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702697/utilize-ado-net-within-classic-asp-script

Comment: That example only caters for one parameter though right?

Comment: Well its been a long time since I used ADO but I highly doubt there is a limitation on the CreateParameter method regarding the amount of times used. The posted example is concerned with only one parameter though, that's correct. Have a look here for more API descriptions http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp